# Scanner skipping input, possible white space?

Tags: java

I just started Java and wanted to tinker with the syntax. Whenever I input "F" into `gender` and `age` being greater than or equal to 20 I should be prompted to input if the user is married or not, for some reason the scanner is skipping over it. Everything else works fine.

Output I'm getting:

```
Whats is your gender (M or F): F
First name: Kim
Last name: Kardashian
Age: 32

Are you married, Kim (Y or N)? 
Then I shall call you Ms. Kardashian.
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GenderGame 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int age = 0;
        String Gender = null, fName = null, lName = null, M = null, type = null;

        System.out.print("Whats is your gender (M or F): ");
        Gender = sc.nextLine();
        Gender = Gender.toUpperCase();

        System.out.print("First name: ");
        fName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Last name: ");
        lName = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Age: ");
        age = sc.nextInt();

        if(Gender.equals("F") && age >= 20)
        {
            System.out.print("\nAre you married, " + fName + " (Y or N)? ");
            M = sc.nextLine();
            M = M.toUpperCase();

            if(M.equals("Y"))
            {
                type = "Mrs. ";
                type = type.concat(lName);
            }
            else
            {
                type = "Ms. ";
                type = type.concat(lName);
            }
        }
        else if(Gender.equals("F") && age < 20)
        {
            type = fName.concat(" " + lName);
        }
        else if(Gender.equals("M") && age >= 20)
        {
            type = "Mr. ";
            type = type.concat(lName);
        }
        else if(Gender.equals("M") && age < 20)
        {
            type = fName.concat(" " + lName);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("There was incorrect input. EXITING PROGRAM");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("\nThen I shall call you " +type+ ".");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextInt()` method of `Scanner` leaves the new line character out, that is, it does not consume it. This newline character is is consumed by your `nextLine()` method, which is why you do not see it wait for your input.

To avoid this, call `sc.nextLine()` after `age = sc.nextInt();`, then leave the rest of code unchanged.

```
        ...
        System.out.print("Age: ");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); //added

        if(Gender.equals("F") && age >= 20)
        {
            System.out.print("\nAre you married, " + fName + " (Y or N)? ");
            M = sc.nextLine();
            M = M.toUpperCase();

            if(M.equals("Y"))
            {
                type = "Mrs. ";
                type = type.concat(lName);
            }
         ...
```